# Conditionally binarizing matrices

Tags: matrix

I want to (fastly) convert matrices with values that are <= a threshold to binary matrices.

[image]

I used a call to Binarize, but I don't like the Image and ImageData conversions as they obfuscate the code. This code is also meant to be didactical and I obtain the matrices from real images in the real use case.

I couldn't write a faster thing using conditionals.

Suggestions?

Comment: `Boole[Map[#<=95&,mat,{2}]]`?

Comment: Please post correctly formatted, copy-and-pastable *Mathematica* code instead of screenshots (at 581 rep, you must have heard this by now, right?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat = {{209, 64, 112}, {8, 96, 253}, {65, 200, 95}};
Unitize[mat, 95];
```

This is fast, but not faster than your version:

```
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 300}, {1000, 1000}];
Unitize[mat, 95]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
ImageData[Binarize[Image[mat], 94]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
UnitStep[mat - 95]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Boole[Map[# <= 95 &, mat, {2}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Sign[mat - 95] /. {-1 -> 0}; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

[image]

and

```
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 300}, {10000, 10000}];
Unitize[mat, 95]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
ImageData[Binarize[Image[mat], 94]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
UnitStep[mat - 95]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

[image]

Comment: The only potential issue with `Unitize` is numbers less than `-t` will be 1, not 0. But if OP's matrices have nonnegative elements, it's not a problem.

Comment: @ChipHurst. Yeah, I actually always forget about that behavior of `Unitize`. I imagine in this case it's good, since he obtains the data from images.

Answer (score 4):

I think this does what you're asking for.

```
t = 95;
M = {{209, 64, 112}, {8, 96, 253}, {65, 200, 95}};

UnitStep[M - t]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `Sign` function, though you have to replace the `-1` with 0

```
Sign[m - t] /. {-1 -> 0}
```